# R group by column, count the combinations observed

Tags: r

I imagine this is already solved in many places, but I lack the right wordage to use to search for a solution.     In R I have example data in long format like this:

`A = tibble( c(1,2,3,1,2,4,5,5), c('a','b','c','a','f','-','b', 'f'))`

and what I want returned is sort of a grouped result (something like a spread?) where I first collect the set of letters that match each number to get something like this.

```
1: 'a', 'a'
2: 'b', 'f'
3: 'c', 'c'
4: '_'
5: 'b', 'f'
```

and the actual final result I am looking for is the count of how many times each letter combination, when is observed:

```
'a','a': 1
'b','f': 2
'c','c': 1
'-': 1
```

I can do the last step with group_by() but I mention it here in case there is some magic sauce that does the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

This is close to what you are looking for:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
A <- structure(list(v1 = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 5), v2 = c("a", "b", 
"c", "a", "f", "-", "b", "f")), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

#Code
A %>% group_by(v1) %>% summarise(chain=paste0(v2,collapse = ',')) %>% ungroup() %>%
  group_by(chain) %>% summarise(N=n())

# A tibble: 4 x 2
  chain     N
  <chr> <int>
1 -         1
2 a,a       1
3 b,f       2
4 c         1
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do a group by 'a', then `paste` the second column while taking the number of distinct elements in 'b' and get the `distinct` rows

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
A %>% 
    group_by(a) %>% 
    summarise(out = str_c(b, collapse=","), n = n_distinct(b))%>% 
    distinct(out, n)
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  out       n
#  <chr> <int>
#1 a,a       1
#2 b,f       2
#3 c         1
#4 -         1
```

#### data

```
A <- structure(list(a = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 5), b = c("a", "b", 
"c", "a", "f", "-", "b", "f")), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R option using nested `aggregate`

```
aggregate(.~y,aggregate(y~.,A,toString),length)
```

which gives

```
> aggregate(.~y,aggregate(y~.,A,toString),length)
     y x
1    - 1
2 a, a 1
3 b, f 2
4    c 1
```

**Data**

```
A = tibble(x =  c(1,2,3,1,2,4,5,5), y = c('a','b','c','a','f','-','b', 'f'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to cast the data in wide format and then `count` the combinations. Try :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

A %>%
  group_by(v1) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number())  %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = row, values_from = v2, names_prefix = 'col_') %>%
  ungroup %>%
  count(col_1, col_2)


#  col_1 col_2     n
#  <chr> <chr> <int>
#1 -     NA        1
#2 a     a         1
#3 b     f         2
#4 c     NA        1
```